# Prove the sequence $x_n=(1+x_{n-1})/2$ converges to $1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ where $x_0 \in \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

The question asks to use the monotone convergence theorem.

My approach:

I could prove that $x_n = 1 + \dfrac{x_0 -1}{2^n}$

I claimed,

When $x_0 \geq 1$, $x_n $ decreases and $x_n$ is bounded below by $1$.

$\dfrac{x_0 -1}{2^n} \geq 0 \rightarrow 1+\dfrac{x_0 -1}{2^n} \geq 1 \rightarrow x_n \geq 1$

To show decreasing,

$\dfrac{x_0 -1}{2^n} > \dfrac{x_0 -1}{2^{n+1}}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$

$1+\dfrac{x_0 -1}{2^n} > 1+ \dfrac{x_0 -1}{2^{n+1}}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$

$x_n > x_{n+1} $ for all $n \in \mathbb N$

Similarly, I took the case $2$ as $x_0 < 1$, where $x_n$ increases and bounded above by $1$

Then I used monotone convergence theorem to say the limit exists and showed that $\dfrac{x_0 -1}{2^n}$ approaches to $0$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$. Hence $x_n \rightarrow 1$

Am I correct here?

Answer (score 1):

> I could prove that $x_n = 1 + \dfrac{x_0 -1}{2^n}$

Since you have found the general formula for $x_n$, you could compute it directly.

$|x_0-1|$ is bounded by some constant number $M>0$, $|x_0-1|\le M$, so we have

$$0\le\left|\frac{x_0-1}{2^n}\right|\le\frac{M}{2^n}<\epsilon$$ So we get the limit,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_0-1}{2^n}=0$$

Therefore, $\lim x_n=1$

Comment: Yeah but the question asks to use the monotone convergence theorem. that's why ..

Comment: Ah, I see, but have you tried to prove it without computing the exact formula of $a_n$? You can try to prove it only by using the recurrence relation.

Comment: Nah. I thought it would be easy to use the exact formula. Somehow, I proved it using the formula I mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0):

When $x_0\leq 1 $ then the sequence is bounded above by 1 and monotonic increasing and if $1\leq x_0 $ then it is bounded below by 1 and monotonic decreasing. Hence it’s convergent to say l. Then l= (1+l)/2 which gives l=1. $